# I cant get user details to save properly in a session

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, session

I am trying to create a chat box and I cant get user_id to save properly in a session after logging in and saving in the database.

This is login function

```
public function login() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        // return main page if submitted form is invalid.

        $this->load->view('abt_login');
    } else {

        $this->load->model('abt_db');
        $q = $this->abt_db->check_login(
                $this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('password')
        );
        if ($q) {

            redirect('index.php/abovetheblues/abt_abovetheblues');
            $this->abt->set_session();
        } else {
            $this->show_login(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a#submit").click(function(){

        var chat_message_content = $("input#chat").val();

        if(chat_message_content == ""){

            return false;
        }

        $.post(base_url + "index.php/abovetheblues/add_chat_messages", {
            chat_message_content : chat_message_content, 
            user_id : user_id
        }, 
        function(data){

            alert(data);
        },"json");


        return false;
    });
    return false;

});
```

This is my controller

```
function add_chat_messages() {
        // Grab the $chat_message_content, $user_id
        $user_id = $this->input->post($this->session->userdata("user_id"));
        $chat_message_content = $this->input->post('chat_message_content');

        $this->abt_db->add_chat_message($user_id, $chat_message_content);
    }
```

This is my model

```
function check_login($email, $password) {
    $this->load->database();
    // Query to retrieve the user's details
    // based on the received username and password

    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $q = $this->db->get()->result();

    // The results of the query are stored in $q.
    // If a value exists, then the user account exists and is validated

    if (is_array($q) && count($q) == 1) {
        // Set the users details into the $details property of this class
        $this->details = $q[0];
        // Call set_session to set the user's session 
        $this->set_session();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


   function set_session() {
        // session->set_userdata is a CodeIgniter function that
        // stores data in a cookie in the user's browser.  Some of the values are built in
        // to CodeIgniter, others are added (like the user_id).  
        $this->session->set_userdata(array(
            'user_id' => $this->details->user_id,
            'email' => $this->details->email,
            'username' => $this->details->username,
            'isLoggedIn' => true
                )
        );
    }


function add_chat_message($user_id, $chat_message_content) {

    $query_str = "INSERT INTO chat_message(user_id, chat_message_content) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $this->db->query($query_str, array($user_id, $chat_message_content));
}
```

And my view page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var user_id = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata("user_id"); ?>";
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";



</script>

<!--loads the header-->
<?php $this->load->view('abt-header'); ?>
<!--this is the login page-->

<div data-role="page" id="Abt-chat" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Peer Chat</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <div id="chat_viewport"></div>

            <p>
                <label>Input Chat: </label>
                <input name="chat" id="chat" type="text" value=""/>

            </p>

            <p>
                <?php echo anchor('#', 'Send Chat', array('title' => 'Send Chat', 'id' => 'submit')); ?>
            </p>  

        </div> 
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It may help if you also posted a test URL, so we could look at the site.

Answer (score 0):

well if user_id is already defined in session then no need to send it every time trough you javascript, or define in page as javascript variable.

in controller you have to give variable name passed trough javascript, bu you are calling session data which will give you id not the variable name

```
$user_id = $this->input->post($this->session->userdata("user_id")); // wrong

$user_id = $this->input->post("user_id"); // right

$user_id = $this->session->userdata("user_id"); // this way without pass through javascript
```

Comment: How do I write it if I have to pass it through javascript

Comment: with javascript just add this $user_id = $this->input->post("user_id");

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes in your code:

I start from your **Model**:

The most important issue here is: You **SHOULD NOT** store user's password in database, that's a really **bad** practice, use PHP [`crypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function with `BLOWFISH` hashing type to encrypt the password, then save the encrypted version in your database. There are couple of [Hashing libraries](https://github.com/HashemQolami/CodeIgniter-PBKDF2-Library) available like [PHPASS](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) you might want to consider.

Check the comments inside, carefully:

```
function check_login($email, $password)
{
    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->from('user')
             ->where('email', $email)
             ->where('password', $password); // <-- Check the encryped password

    $q = $this->db->get();

    if ($q->num_rows() == 1) {
        // Set the users details into the $details property of this class
        $this->details = $q->first_row();
         // Call set_session to set the user's session 
        $this->set_session();
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

function set_session()
{
    $this->session->set_userdata(array(
        'user_id'    => $this->details->user_id,
        'email'      => $this->details->email,
        'username'   => $this->details->username/*,
        // You don't need to store this in session
        // If user is logged-in, his/her user_id would be in session
        // you can easily check whether user is logged-in or not
        // by looking for user_id in session.
        'isLoggedIn' => true*/
    ));
}

function add_chat_message($user_id, $chat_message_content)
{
    // You are binding two parameter to SQL query,
    // But the following query has three question mark.
    // $query_str = "INSERT INTO chat_message(user_id, chat_message_content) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $query_str = "INSERT INTO chat_message(user_id, chat_message_content) VALUES (?,?)";
    $this->db->query($query_str, array($user_id, $chat_message_content));
}
```

Back into your `login()` function, lines are after `redirect()` won't be executed:

```
redirect('index.php/abovetheblues/abt_abovetheblues');
// $this->abt->set_session(); <-- This is not necessary
```

In your `Controller/add_chat_messages` method, using `$this->input->post($this->session->userdata("user_id")` is wrong.

If user has to be logged-in in website, it isn't necessary to pass the user's `id` via POST request. Just read it from session:

```
function add_chat_messages()
{
    // The following statement is wrong!
    //$user_id = $this->input->post($this->session->userdata("user_id"));

    $user_id = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
    $chat_message_content = $this->input->post('chat_message_content');

    $this->abt_db->add_chat_message($user_id, $chat_message_content);
}
```

And finally, in client-side, JavaScript section:

You don't need to send user's id to the server, because those user's have access to chat page which are already logged-in:

```
$.post(base_url + "index.php/abovetheblues/add_chat_messages", {
    chat_message_content : chat_message_content/*, 
    user_id : user_id*/ // <-- This is not necessary
}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
},"json");
```

Hope it makes sense.

**Update #1:**

Before using `session`, make sure `Session` library is loaded.

Open up `config/autoload.php` file and add `session` to autoload libraries:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

**Update #2:**

Change `check_login` and `set_session` functions in your **Model** to:

```
function check_login($email, $password)
{
    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->from('user')
             ->where('email', $email)
             ->where('password', $password);

    $q = $this->db->get();

    if ($q->num_rows() == 1) {
        // Return the users details
        return $q->first_row('array');
    }

    return FALSE;
}

function set_session($details)
{
    $this->session->set_userdata(array(
        'user_id'    => $details['user_id'],
        'email'      => $details['email'],
        'username'   => $details['username']
    ));
}
```

And in your **Controller**:

```
if ($q) {
    $this->abt_db->set_session($q);
    redirect('index.php/abovetheblues/abt_abovetheblues');
} else {
    $this->show_login(true);
}
```

Finally in your JS file, remove the `json` `dataType` from `$.post` method.

And one more thing, `abovetheblues/add_chat_messages` method doesn't send anything to the output (doesn't echo anything), So the returned `data` is empty:

```javascript
$.post(base_url + "index.php/abovetheblues/add_chat_messages", {
    chat_message_content : chat_message_content/*, 
    user_id : user_id*/
}, function(data){
    // data would be empty
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: I have made those corrections but it still does not save the user Id in the session, how do I post the user_id if it has to go through Javascript

Comment: I have done that earlier and still does not work, when I view it the response in firebug it does not seem to hold the user_id in the session, could it be that firebug is blocking it.?

Comment: @Omade I highly recommend to store sessions [in database](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) and set `$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']` to `TRUE`. BTW, in `set_session()` function, make sure `$this->details->user_id` exists and isn't empty (use `var_dump`). Do the same test on `add_chat_message()` Controller/method for `$user_id`.

Comment: That is the problem I have the user_id is empty when I do the test.

Comment: Another thing i suspect is the ajax post I have done in Javascript but honestly I am stocked and do not know what to do

Comment: Before debugging the `ajax` action, you should fix the `user_id` issue. after user `POST` the login form, you call `check_login()` method, make sure `$q->first_row();` returns a value before calling the `set_session()` method. `var_dump($this->details);`

Comment: Can you please edit the code above as I am confused on where to put the $q->first_row();

Comment: @Omade Check the first code block, in your Model, find `$q->first_row();` and put `var_dump($this->details);` after that line.

Comment: and please don't ask same questions multiple times on SO.

Comment: If `$q->first_row();` returns no data (empty), there's nothing wrong with your Session or etc. make sure the user exists in database. Also after `$q = $this->db->get();` write this line: `var_dump($q->result_array());` and let me know what it returns.

Comment: Give me more details please, what does that `var_dump` return?

Comment: Its not returning anything to the browser

Comment: If `$q->result_array()` doesn't return anything, it means there's no record in database for that user.

Comment: It returns an array of values in the database